# How to re-position the grid layout elements in fragments on orientation change?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, grid-layout

I am having a bottom tabbed activity with three fragments Home, Dashboard and Notifications. In the first fragment, I am having 4 layouts with a button in each layout. These 4 layouts are aligned ina grid view having positions as column:rows (1:1 1:2 2:1 2:2) while in portrait orientation.

But how to auto-arrange these layouts when in landscape mode i.e. either as (1:1 1:2 1:3 1:4) based on the horizontal area available during landscape?

[image]

Xml File

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:grid2="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/container2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#00555555"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        grid2:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
        grid2:columnCount="2"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        grid2:rowOrderPreserved="false">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout1"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:text="TextView"
            grid2:layout_column="0"
            grid2:layout_gravity="center"
            grid2:layout_row="0">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/but1"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="56dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/button1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    grid2:layout_gravity="left" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text="@string/control"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:textStyle="italic" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#25F325"
                    android:text="@string/no_status"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout2"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            grid2:layout_column="1"
            grid2:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            grid2:layout_row="0">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/but2"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="56dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/button2" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:textStyle="italic"
                    android:textSize="21sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/no_data"
                    android:textColor="#25F325"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout3"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            grid2:layout_column="0"
            grid2:layout_gravity="center"
            grid2:layout_row="1">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/but3"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/img1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Fire"
                    android:textSize="21sp"
                    android:textStyle="italic" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/no_data"
                    android:textColor="#25F325"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout4"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:text="TextView"
            grid2:layout_column="1"
            grid2:layout_gravity="center"
            grid2:layout_row="1">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/but4"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/gas1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Gas"
                android:textSize="21sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#25F325"
                android:text="@string/no_data
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

</androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>
</ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Home Fragment Class

```
    package com.example.qnorb.ui.home;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;

import com.example.qnorb.R;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        homeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
       // textView = root.findViewById(R.id.lights);
        homeViewModel.getText().observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
            }
        });
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }
}
```

Home View Model Class

```
 package com.example.qnorb.ui.home;

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;

public class HomeViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<String> mText;

    public HomeViewModel() {
        mText = new MutableLiveData<>();
    }

    public LiveData<String> getText() {
        return mText;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you add `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|keyboardHidden" `??

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes

Answer (score 0):

Target API 13+:

Set the android:configChanges flag in your Activity in manifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name="com.test.activity.MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"/>
```

Comment: Nothing happening

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use `RecyclerView` pattern with different `spanCount` after rotation configuration changes.

Also you can calculate span count by screen width or whatever.

So basically in `onCreate()`, set new `GridLayoutManager(context, GRID_SPAN_COUNT_BY_ROTATION)` in to`RecyclerView`

it should look like this in your fragment:

```
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        homeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.your_recyclerview);


        // set span count by orientation
        int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        int spanCount;
        if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            // code for portrait mode
            spanCount = 4;
        } else {
            // code for landscape mode
            spanCount = 9;
        }

        // set GridLayoutManager with custom span count
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, spanCount));

        homeViewModel.getText().observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
            }
        });
        return root;
    }
```

if it is not working then do not forget to change manifest config rules like mentioned in another answer.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little further? What exactly to add in oncreate()?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have two different layouts for portrait and landscape orientation.

it should be named same name, but in different layout directories:

`layout` dir where your current layout is for Portrait orientation.

Now create `layout-land` directory, copy same layout and refactor it with same view id's just different positions.

It should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Ok got it but one issue with this might be since the position is static thus it might not work with different screen sizes. Even if I change grid positions still that might be valid for a specific screen size. I think just like you mentioned earlier the best dynamic way could be to use recycler view with grid-layout and then look for screen size changes and adjust grids accordingly using layout manager, Right?

Comment: Yes for sure it is mutch better to use dynamic RecyclerView with adapter and GridLayoutManger. Sorry did not saw it at first that you are using simple GridLayout. I will unhide that post